# How to write Entity Framework query to be able to join to the ICollection?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I'm trying to work out the Entity Framework syntax to return the `User.Name`, `User.Email` for the given `Profile.email`.

1 profile can have N categories. 1 category can have 1 User.

- Profile - ID, email, Name, CreatedDate
- Category - ID, ProfileId, Name, UserID
- User - ID, Name, Email

In SQL I would write:

```
SELECT U.NAME, U.EMAIL
FROM PROFILE P
JOIN CATEGORY C ON P.ID = C.PROFILEID
JOIN USER U ON C.USERID = U.ID
WHERE P.EMAIL = 'SOME@EMAIL.COM'
```

Here is what I tried:

```
var data = await _context.Profiles
                         .AsNoTracking()
                         .Where(p => p.Categories.Users.email == 'some@email.com')
                         .Select(u => new 
                                      {
                                          UName = u.Name,
                                          UEmail = u.Email
                                      }).ToListAsync();
```

The problem is that `p.Categories` is an `ICollection`, so I don't know how to proceed because `p.Categories` doesn't give me access to the `.Users`. I can write `p.Categories.Where....` but I'm not sure how to proceed.

Instead of starting with `_context.Profiles.` should I be starting with `_context.Users.`?

Can someone help me on how to think about the approach when writing the Entity Framework query?

Comment: I think your model is not clear... 
There are more categories for each profile? If its so you will get more than one user in your query results, As a suggestion before going direclty in funcional style, try to write the query using `from a in _context.Table` form that is similar to SLQ-like sintax

Comment: yes the output maybe more than 1 user

Comment: What role does the Categories play here? I would start by querying the users table, and filter by category if needed.

Comment: 1 profile can have N categories. 1 category can have 1 User.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understood your model correctly, this should work:

```
var data = await _context.Categories.AsNoTracking()
                     .Where(c=>c.Profile.email == "some@email.com")
                     .Select(c=>new {
                         UName=c.User.Name,
                         UEmail=c.User.Email
                     }).ToListAsync();
```

Ofcourse this requires your model to have navigation properties set.

Comment: How did you think of starting from Categories and not from Users or Profile?

Comment: @variable in relational databases there are no roots. You can start from any table. An `INNER JOIN` has no direction. You can do the same in C# if relations are two-way.

Comment: You could start from Profile too, but in my opinion your object model best suits querying by categories, since that has direct relations to both users and profiles, and basicly you are searching for categories.

Comment: This works great. Please can you also provide a sample of how the code would look suppose I started from User or Profile table?

Comment: You have a way of starting with Profiles table below in David Browne's answer. If you have the navigation properties set, it would be possible to start with Users table too, but I don't see why you'd want to do that. I think it would make a more complex query than the other options.

Answer (score 2):

So just start your query the Categories in LINQ form:

```
from c in _context.Categories
where c.Profile.Email == someEmail
select new { c.User.Name, c.User.Email }
```

or in Lambda form:

```
   _context.Categories
           .Where( c => c.Profile.Email == someEmail )
           .Select( c => new {c.User.Name, c.User.Email}
```

or start from Profiles and use [SelectMany](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany?view=net-6.0), whose LINQ form looks like

```
from p in _context.Profiles
from c in p.Categories
where p.Email == someEmail
select new {c.User.Name, c.User.Email}
```

or in Lambda form:

```
_context.Profiles
        .Where(p => p.Email == someEmail)
        .SelectMany(p => p.Categories)
        .Select( c => new {c.User.Name, c.User.Email} )
```

Comment: Entity framework will automatically join profiles and categories?

Comment: Yes.  Your Navigation Properties define joins you can use without an explicit JOIN operator.

Comment: Can you convert that 2nd code into the other LINQ syntax? I will be happy to learn how it looks.